# Multiple nesting of reactive inputs in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In shiny I am creating an app which will allow users to select different functions to use, and so it will require different input variables. I am able to get the first level of nesting to work, however if I try a second level of nested inputs it does not recognise them, as it seems that it cannot read it's own input.

I have tried to set the 2nd level inputs to NULL, and then using an if statement they are meant to change to be an actual input, but it doesn't show up.

Here is an example app.R using the standard Old Faithful Geyser data.

```r
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel({


      uiOutput("input_ui")
    }),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$input_ui <- renderUI({
    B <- sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)

    Den <- radioButtons("den", "Density", choices = c("Yes", "No"), selected = "No")
    bw.input = NULL
    if(Den == "Yes"){
      bw.input <- numericInput("bw", "BandWidth", min = 1, max = 5, step = 0.1, value = 1)

    }

    list(B, Den, bw.input)
  })


  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, border = 'white', col = "grey", freq = F)
    if(input$den == "Yes"){
      lines(density(x,bw,add = T))
    }
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here, I am trying to have it so that if the user wants to plot the density plot over the histogram they can, and they can change the bandwidth if it is selected.

Instead, when `density - Yes` is selected it produces the error message `argument is of length zero` and the bandwidth input doesn't appear.

How can I change the above code so that it allows the extra input? I know the format of the code looks odd, but it is what I need to do for other components of my app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked `observeEvent()`? Perhaps [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/mutually-dependent-numericinput-in-shiny/29307) can also help you.

Comment: As is `input$den` is not evaluated in the server, so the app doesn't know that it is supposed to do anything. Look at `?conditionalPanel` to render a widget based on status of another widget. Or use another `renderUI` to output the `numericInput`.

Comment: It looks like your renderUI call does not depend on any reactive values or inputs, so why not move all the slider and radio buttons into the UI and only keep the numericInput in the server function.